# How to define and implement properties in protocol

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties, protocols

I want to define one protocol with few properties and need to use those properties in another NSObject subclass. Please give me link or example code. I need that to work with 10.5.

Thanks
    PLEASE CHECK THE FOLLOWING SAMPLE CODE

```
@protocol MyProtocol
@property (nonatomic, readonly) id someObject;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isAlive) BOOL alive;
@end

#import "MyProtocol.h"
@interface MyCustomClass : NSObject <MyProtocol>{

}
@end

#import "MyCustomClass.h"
@implementation MyCustomClass
@synthesize someObject,alive;

/*
- (id)someObject {
    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)isAlive {
    return YES;
}

- (void)setAlive:(BOOL)aBOOL {
}
*/
@end
```

**Added:
Compling code with x86_64 architecture works fine. But error if i'll change the architecture to i386, then i am getting following warnings:

```
MyCustomClass.m:13: error: synthesized property 'someObject' must either be named the same as a compatible ivar or must explicitly name an ivar

 error: synthesized property 'alive' must either be named the same as a compatible ivar or must explicitly name an ivar
```

I just want to know why it is working in x86_64 with @synthesize and not in i386.**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`@property` just says to the compiler that the class is expected to define the methods to match that property.

```
@protocol MyProtocol
@property (nonatomic, readonly) id someObject;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isAlive) BOOL alive;
@end
```

Anything implementing that protocol will now need to have

```
- (id)someObject;
- (BOOL)isAlive;
- (void)setAlive:(BOOL)aBOOL;
```

Comment: Synthesizing the properties should work as well, since it instructs the compiler to supply the accessor method implementations.

Comment: Thanks, your provided code work perfectly, if i keep the project architecture to x86_64. If i change the architecture to i386 then i am getting following warnings:

MyCustomClass.m:13: error: synthesized property 'someObject' must either be named the same as a compatible ivar or must explicitly name an ivar

 error: synthesized property 'alive' must either be named the same as a compatible ivar or must explicitly name an ivar

I just want to know why it is working in x86_64 with @synthesize and not in i386.

Thanks

Comment: I am trying to write less code if possible. Please also explain me what is the difference between different architectures and which one i suppose to choose to compile the application.

Comment: x86-64 uses the new runtime, i386 uses the old one. On the new runtime @synthesize doesn't require a backing ivar for synthesized properties.

Comment: So,Is that means, that i must compile my app with i386 architecture to keep 10.5 compatibility?

Comment: 10.5 supports 64bit apps. You'd lose support for Intel CoreDuo though. All other intel macs will run 64 bit binaries fine

Comment: @JoshuaWeinberg It's kind of old now but I wanted to ask why are properties declarations even allowed in protocols. Can't we just have method declarations which subscribers will implement. That would achieve the same thing. Am I missing something. Or is accessibility using the . (dot operator) the intent for allowing properties in protocols.

Answer (score 1):

I think the things you're dealing with are primarily side effects of the introduction of [Objective-C 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C_2.0). It lets you do things like declare properties without also defining instance vars. But (as you have discovered), it is only x86_64 and post-10.5 compatible.

Comment: I have a similar error.  I checked the box "built active architecture only" for x86_64.  It fixed it.