# iOS how to implement a protocol's @property

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

What I understand is that a protocol specify method names, and someone else who conforms to that protocol do the implementation of the methods.

So what about the properties declared in a protocol? Is that to implement a property means to implement its setter and getter?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844678/how-to-handle-objective-c-protocols-that-contain-properties and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377869/how-to-define-and-implement-properties-in-protocol

Comment: Thanks. Yet we get a better and more concise answer here by @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Property is a fancy name for one or two methods with specific signatures for which Objective-C provides a convention that lets you call them using the alternative dot `.` syntax. There is no difference between a protocol declaring, say, a pair of

```
-(int) foo;
-(void)setFoo:(int)_foo;
```

methods, and a protocol declaring a read-write property:

```
 @property (readwrite) foo;
```

So you are absolutely right, implementing a property means implementing one or two methods, depending on whether you implement a read-only, write-only, or a read-write property.

Comment: Very well explained. Now I get it.

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, you just have to implements the getter and or setter (depending on the property).

I would add that you can just synthesize them :

> @property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject * foo;

would end up in :

> @synthesize foo;

Answer (score 0):

A protocol is just something that's makes sure that an object implements a set of methods. If you were to use an object as a delegate of your class for example, you would want to make sure that it implemented the methods that you're going to call. That's the point of a protocol.