# Objective-c on the protocol defined a property protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, protocols

I read some code, I founded the `@protocol` have defined a `@property`'s protocol.

For example

protocol1.h

```
@protocol protocol2;
@protocol protocol1

-(void)p1_method1;
-(void)p1_method2;

@property (readonly, nonatomic) id<protocol2>p2;

@end
```

protocol2.h

```
@protocol protocol2

-(void)p2_method1;
-(void)p2_method2;

@end
```

I don't know the protocol have a `@property` protocol mean. 
Have a simple example? Thanks.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746986/ios-how-to-implement-a-protocols-property?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is `@synthesize p2` in a class that conforms to `protocol1`.  Properties from protocols don't get automatically synthesised.

```
@interface Class1 : NSObject <protocol1>

@end

@implementation Class1

@synthesize p2;      // Synthesize p2, the property from protocol1

- (void)p1_method1 {
    // Do something    
}

- (void)p1_method2 {
    // Do something else
}
```

This will create the correct getter/setter for the property (in your example the property is readonly so only a getter).  The `@synthesize` will also create the ivar, in this case `p2`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add protocol above the interface you will be using.

```
@protocol MyViewControllerDelegate;

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <MyViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSArray *viewControllers;
@end

@protocol MyViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

//sth
@end
```