# why protocol can have @property but not iVar?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I read somewhere that "`property` actually is just get/set method, it need not backing variable". is that true?
if true where property store its value

Comment: Possible you can find an answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377869/how-to-define-and-implement-properties-in-protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you add a `protocol`  you are just saying that who want implement that protocol must provide the same property or a set/get for that variable.

If your protocol "require"  a property and your class doesn't provide it you will receive a warning

> Auto property  synthesis  will not synthesize  property 'varname' declared in protocol 'protocolname'

Answer (score 1):

Properties are *method* declarations. Period. This is why you can have them in a protocol.

But the base of your Q leads to properties and synthesizing, not to protocols:

The backing ivar is created through the synthesizing of the property in an implementation, if there is no connected ivar. Since we have automatic synthesizing, you do not see that synthesizing. But it is still there.

So, a source code like this

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property id prop;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@end
```

Silently adds something like this. (It is not exactly the same, but almost.)

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property id prop;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize prop;
@end
```

You can check that, if you implement the accessors of a declared property manually:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property id prop;
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (id)prop { … };
- (void)setProp:(id)prop { … };
@end
```

In such a case automatic synthesizing is turned off and no ivar is declared.

So, if ivars are a matter of *implementation*, protocols cannot declare them. They are a kind of *interface* definition.

Answer (score -2):

When you implement that protocol as part of a class, that class will synthesize the underlying instance vars. The protocol, as you'd know, is just a declaration.